# Processing - deprecated OpenKinect library

Tags: processing

I am trying to replicate a project for Kinect for [this music video](http://moullinex.tumblr.com/post/3180520798/catalina-music-video), but the code is seriously outdated.

After weeks searching, I have not found anything about this.

I would be greatly thankful to anyone who points out to me what is deprecated in the following code:

(I'm using `Processing 3`)

```
import org.openkinect.*;
import org.openkinect.processing.*;

import java.io.*;

// Kinect Library object
Kinect kinect;

float a = 0;

// Size of kinect image
int w = 640;
int h = 480;

// writing state indicator
boolean write = false;

// treshold filter initial value
int fltValue = 950;


// "recording" object. each vector element holds a coordinate map vector
Vector <Object> recording = new Vector<Object>(); 


// We'll use a lookup table so that we don't have to repeat the math over and     over
float[] depthLookUp = new float[2048];

 void setup() {
 size(800,600,P3D);
 kinect = new Kinect(this);
 kinect.start();
 kinect.enableDepth(true);
 // We don't need the grayscale image in this example
 // so this makes it more efficient
 kinect.processDepthImage(false);

 // Lookup table for all possible depth values (0 - 2047)
 for (int i = 0; i < depthLookUp.length; i++) {
  depthLookUp[i] = rawDepthToMeters(i);
 }

}

void draw() {

background(0);
fill(255);
textMode(SCREEN);
text("Kinect FR: " + (int)kinect.getDepthFPS() + "\nProcessing FR: " +   (int)frameRate,10,16);

// Get the raw depth as array of integers
int[] depth = kinect.getRawDepth();

// We're just going to calculate and draw every 4th pixel (equivalent of 160x120)
int skip = 4;

// Translate and rotate
translate(width/2,height/2,-50);
rotateY(a);

//noStroke();
 //lights();


int index = 0;


PVector[] frame = new PVector[19200];


for(int x=0; x<w; x+=skip) {
  for(int y=0; y<h; y+=skip) {
    int offset = x+y*w;

  // Convert kinect data to world xyz coordinate
  int rawDepth = depth[offset];

  boolean flt = true;
  PVector v = depthToWorld(x,y,rawDepth);
  if (flt && rawDepth > fltValue)
  {
    v = depthToWorld(x,y,2047);
  }

  frame[index] = v;

  index++;   

  stroke(map(rawDepth,0,2048,0,256));
  pushMatrix();
  // Scale up by 200
  float factor = 400;
  translate(v.x*factor,v.y*factor,factor-v.z*factor);
  //sphere(1);
  point(0,0);

  //line (0,0,1,1);
  popMatrix();
  }
 }

if (write == true) {
recording.add(frame);    

}


// Rotate
//a += 0.015f;
}

// These functions come from:http://graphics.stanford.edu/~mdfisher/Kinect.html
 float rawDepthToMeters(int depthValue) {
  if (depthValue < 2047) {
   return (float)(1.0 / ((double)(depthValue) * -0.0030711016 + 3.3309495161));
  }
 return 0.0f;
 }

 PVector depthToWorld(int x, int y, int depthValue) {

final double fx_d = 1.0 / 5.9421434211923247e+02;
final double fy_d = 1.0 / 5.9104053696870778e+02;
final double cx_d = 3.3930780975300314e+02;
final double cy_d = 2.4273913761751615e+02;

PVector result = new PVector();
double depth =  depthLookUp[depthValue];//rawDepthToMeters(depthValue);
result.x = (float)((x - cx_d) * depth * fx_d);
result.y = (float)((y - cy_d) * depth * fy_d);
result.z = (float)(depth);
return result;
}

void stop() {
kinect.quit();
super.stop();
}


int currentFile = 0;

void saveFile() {

}

void keyPressed() { // Press a key to save the data

if (key == '1')
{
fltValue += 50;
println("fltValue: " + fltValue);
}
else if (key == '2')
{
fltValue -= 50;
println("fltValue: " + fltValue);
}
else if (key=='4'){
if (write == true) {
    write = false;

    println( "recorded " + recording.size() + " frames.");

    // saveFile();

    // save    

  Enumeration e = recording.elements();

  println("Stopped Recording " + currentFile);
  int i = 0;
  while (e.hasMoreElements()) {

     // Create one directory
     boolean success = (new File("out"+currentFile)).mkdir(); 


    PrintWriter output = createWriter("out"+currentFile+"/frame" + i++ +".txt");
    PVector [] frame = (PVector []) e.nextElement();

    for (int j = 0; j < frame.length; j++) {
     output.println(j + ", " + frame[j].x + ", " + frame[j].y + ", " + frame[j].z );

    }
    output.flush(); // Write the remaining data
    output.close();
  }
  currentFile++;



  }
}
else if (key == '3') {
    println("Started Recording "+currentFile);
    recording.clear();

    write = true;
 }

}
```

Comment: Does the code work? Does it throw an exception? Exhibit some strange behavior? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

If the code works, then I wouldn't worry too much about it. Deprecated can just mean that a newer version is available, not that the older version stopped working.

However, if the code does not work, then updating to a newer library is probably a good idea anyway. Check out the [library](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/) section of the Processing homepage, which lists several Kinect libraries.

In fact, one of those libraries is the updated version of the old library you're using: [Open Kinect for Processing](http://shiffman.net/p5/kinect/).

Edit: It looks like both of the errors you mentioned are due to missing import statements. You need to import both `Vector` and `Enumeration` to use them:

```
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.Enumeration;
```

Comment: the code does not work...I have added the new `openKinect` library from within `Processing` itself, but the code's syntax is outdated. I was hoping someone could point me which classes in the code are outdated; for instance: I know that former `Vector` class is now `PVector`.  console also says that the function `size()`does not exist, which makes no sense to me, since it is a global method. `Enumeration` does not exist either. and so on.  I'm still in the dark..

Comment: Can you edit your question to post your updated code? Also, `Vector` and `PVector` are completely different classes. `Vector` is like an `ArrayList`, and `PVector` is like a `Point`. Completely different classes.

Comment: I see, thank you. I haven't updated the code, though...the code here is precisely where I'm stuck at.

Comment: @data_garden See the edit to my answer. If you're still having errors, post the updated code (with the added import statements) along with the full text of any errors you're getting, and exactly what lines they're on. But you might be better off looking for a newer example, since these libraries have probably changed quite a bit over the last few years.